# bootstrap: tags in input and typeahead

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead, bootstrap-tags-input

I am trying to use bootstrap [tagsinput](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) in a form contained in a modal
like this

```
...
<div class="form-group">
                            <label for="myTagLabel">Tags:</label> 
                            <input class="form-control" id="myTag"  type="text" data-role="tagsinput">
                        </div>
```

Also I am trying to use [twitter typeahead](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#bloodhound) with the following code

```
var tagValues = ['ATag','AnotherTag'];

    var tagVals = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        local: $.map(tagValues, function(tagValue) { return { value: tagValue }; })
    });

    // kicks off the loading/processing of `local` and `prefetch`
    tagVals.initialize();

    $('#myTag').tagsinput({
        typeaheadjs: {
            name: 'tagVals',
            displayKey: 'value',
            valueKey: 'value',
            source: tagVals.ttAdapter()
        }
    });
```

you can see in the image above what is the result. In this case the problem is that typeahead suggestions are not contained in the frame with rounded corners

[image]

Comment: you need typeahead custom CSS

Comment: You're welcome, I posted the answer with the CSS you need.

Comment: @lowcoupling i am trying to do the same , i am using bootstrap tags input and typeahead js 0.10.5 and it is not working , i want to fetch the results from a remote source. here is my question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399829/user-bootstrap-tags-input-with-typeaheadjs-0-10-5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ripping the CSS from the page; here is the needed CSS that will place suggestions inside of a box. There is much more CSS in the page; but it will override a lot of bootstrap.

```
    /* CSS for typeahead */
.tt-query {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}

.tt-hint {
  color: #999
}

.tt-dropdown-menu {
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 12px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
     -moz-border-radius: 8px;
          border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
          box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.tt-suggestion {
  padding: 3px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #CECBCB;

}
```

Comment: thank you it worked wonderfully. How about why the input has not the width of the container?

Comment: post a http://www.bootply.com/new# with a container and input as you have it set up and i will fix it for you.

Comment: the strange thing is that without data-role="tagsinput" it works (which means it has the same width of the other inputs in the form)

Comment: @lowcoupling sadly bootstrap offers no support for 3rd party plugins, so they might have conflicting CSS.

Comment: but it works fine in this site http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/ although I can't see why

Comment: here is the bootply http://www.bootply.com/j3HkS6kLw9 it lacks of the bootstrap-tagsinput css and js but the input has role="tagsinput". When the bootstrap-tagsinput css is imported the input width starts depending on the content instead of being as wide as the container

Comment: this bootply http://www.bootply.com/f43d1A0YxK completely reproduces the issue. Also check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295620/bootstrap-tags-input-width thank you

Comment: @lowcoupling i will look at it soon, and update if i can find an answer