# bootstrap tags input width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-tags-input

I am trying to use bootstrap [tagsinput](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) in a form contained in a modal
like this

```
...
<div class="form-group">
                            <label for="myTagLabel">Tags:</label> 
                            <input class="form-control" id="myTag"  type="text" data-role="tagsinput">
                        </div>
```

As you can see in the image above I can't see why the input doesn't have the width of the containing form.

**UPDATE**
this http://www.bootply.com/f43d1A0YxK reproduces the issue

[image]

Comment: try `input-sm` class instead of `form-control`

Comment: hi, I have tried, it doesn't work. :(

Comment: for other option if someone want to increase width of [input tags](https://github.com/TimSchlechter/bootstrap-tagsinput/blob/master/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.js#L46) check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/xeu2u1o0/)

Comment: you can set placeholder for your original input and the new input size is adjusted according to the placeholder you added.

Answer (score 51):

The reason you are seeing this behaviour is because `bootstrap-tagsinput` actually hides the original `input` element, and in its place adds a `div`. You are seeing a `div` element styled to look like a Bootstrap input element. So any CSS to affect the original input will not produce any changes.

What you want to change is the `.bootstrap-tagsinput` class:

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Here's a demo: http://www.bootply.com/1iATJfFM69

Comment: after reviewing the demo, I think the better declaration here would be to declare `display:block, width:auto; margin: auto 0;`; that way padding and border declarations do not create issues.

Comment: @Mohamad, If I want to a class to the div "tagdivclass" and style it, how would I add the class?

Comment: @user763410 short of hacking around the plugin's source to add the class, you can add a wrapper element with your custom class, or override the elements CSS...

Comment: @Mohamad, I looked around in the source it seems like a hard coded thing. So, I have to hack around the plugin's source

Comment: needs `display: block`

Comment: add also this line to fix the placeholder
`.bootstrap-tagsinput input{
            width: 100% !important;
 }`

Comment: Why the !important? That seems like overkill.

Answer (score 9):

Add `display: block;` to the `.bootstrap-tagsinput` class in your CSS. As noted by Mohamad this class is not present in your own HTML, but when you inspect element/view source you can see that the input is wrapped in a `<div class="bootstrap-tagsinput">`.

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput{
    display: block;
}
```

This will overwrite the `display: inline-block;` that is being inherited.

#### [Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/5dBPjU7TmM)

Answer (score 2):

Cristian almost guessed it
somewhere in js:

```
$('.bootstrap-tagsinput > input').css('width', '');
```

and in css:

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput input {
  width: 10em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the tagsinput plugin you are using comes with its own css file.

```
bootstrap-tagsinput.css
```

These css rules are automatically being added to your input when you add the data-role="tagsinput".

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 100%;
  line-height: 22px;
  cursor: text;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput input {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: auto !important;
  max-width: inherit;          //Try change this to 100% !important;
  display: block;             // Add this in
}
```

You need to update these so they don't over rule native bootstrap rule.

Comment: I can't see how they have managed to do that here http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Comment: I have added a bootply reproducing the issue

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this problem is, the bootstrap-tagsinput class is using `display: inline-block;`

the solution is, simply change the `display: inline-block;` to `display: block;`

**Before change**

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  padding: 4px 6px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 100%;
  line-height: 22px;
  cursor: text;
}
```

**After change**

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  padding: 4px 6px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 100%;
  line-height: 22px;
  cursor: text;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason you are seeing this behaviour is because the style actually override the width attribute:

```
style="width: 3em ! important;"
```

Remove the style:

```
$('.bootstrap-tagsinput > input').prop( "style", null );
```

This should work properly.

Additionally, set the desired width with CSS:

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput input { width:100%!important; }
```