# how to set bootstrap tagsinput typeahead datasource as ko observablearray

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, typeahead

```
<input data-bind="value:ServicingSelected" class='t1' type='text'
 name='tags' data-role='tagsinput' placeholder='Add tags' />
```

Here `ServicingSelected` is the observablearray that holds the currently selected item on view a record.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
           $('.t1').tagsinput({
               maxTags: 3
           });
       });
```

Now it is showing the selected options properly on view record. But the Typahead source for the same has been kept in a similar observabearray in the view model.

But don't know how to set it as the data source for the typeahead of the bootstrap tags input

I used the below link for ref.
http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

The tags input field is inside a table

```
 <table style="width: 100%" class="table table-striped" 
   data-bind="triggerUpdate: MatchDetails">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tags input docs, the author uses a prefetch and remote json:

```
var citynames = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: {
    url: 'assets/citynames.json',
    filter: function(list) {
      return $.map(list, function(cityname) {
        return { name: cityname }; });
    }
  }
});
citynames.initialize();

$('input').tagsinput({
  typeaheadjs: {
    name: 'citynames',
    displayKey: 'name',
    valueKey: 'name',
    source: citynames.ttAdapter()
  }
});
```

But, in the [typeahead.js docs](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/), we can see there's a `local` parameter available:

```
// constructs the suggestion engine
var states = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  // `states` is an array of state names defined in "The Basics"
  local: $.map(states, function(state) { return { value: state }; })
});

// kicks off the loading/processing of `local` and `prefetch`
states.initialize();

$('#bloodhound .typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'states',
  displayKey: 'value',
  // `ttAdapter` wraps the suggestion engine in an adapter that
  // is compatible with the typeahead jQuery plugin
  source: states.ttAdapter()
});
```

So you can probably use

```
local: myObservableArray().map(function(tag) { return { value: tag }; })
```

However, if you need the typeahead to update whenever the observableArray does, you'll probably need to re-wire things up by initializing the plugin again.

You can accomplish this using a `subscription`: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables

```
myObservableArray.subscribe(function() {
    setupTypeahead();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it worked, using the local parameter itself, but I had to convert observable array to normal array, as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292267/bootstrap-tags-in-input-and-typeahead?rq=1